# SSH ignores my ForwardAgent config?

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to set up Capistrano for a webapp I'm working on, and I'm having trouble getting agent forwarding to work.

Here's my `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host rs
Hostname <ip of my server>
  ForwardAgent yes

User root
```

And I don't think default settings are overriding anything, since `ForwardAgent` is never mentioned there (except in a commented line).

Here's what happens when I SSH normally:

```
$ ssh -v deploy@<server>
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/ulyssecarion/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *

-- snip --

debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.8.0-29-generic x86_64)
```

If I force SSH to allow agent-forwarding with the `-A` flag, then I can get it work:

```
$ ssh -Av deploy@<server>
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/ulyssecarion/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *

-- snip --

debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Requesting authentication agent forwarding. # Note this additional line here
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.8.0-29-generic x86_64)
```

(Notice that the logs on the second example have an additional line indicating agent forwarding is being requested.)

Is this normal, or am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using "rs" as the host name on the command line? Otherwise, the configuration block does not apply.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This block

```
Host rs
  HostName <ip of my server>
  ForwardAgent
  User root
```

only applies if your call to `ssh` looks like

```
ssh rs
```

in which case `ssh` knows that  should be used in place of "rs". In your call

```
ssh -v deploy@<server>
```

whatever you are using as `<server>` does not match "rs" (since only the literal string "rs" is going to match), so the block does not apply.

The argument to the `Host` option must be a pattern which will match the host name you actually use on the command line.

Comment: Hours later, this answer helped me solve it. My problem was having `Host example.com ForwardAgent yes`, followed by corresponding alias missing `ForwardAgent yes`.

Answer (score 1):

There is some great information over on ServerFault about setting up ssh agent forwarding.
https://superuser.com/questions/168933/extra-configuration-required-for-ssh-agent-forwarding

One thing I want to point out, the ssh config file on the server might have ForwardAgent commented out, but at least on my config file, it's really listing the ssh defaults. It seems for some versions of openssh you have to set the AllowAgentForwarding option on the server. I've found this article really useful https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-agent-forwarding

The way to check if ssh agent forwarding is working is by looking at the $SSH_AUTH_SOCK environment variable.

echo "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK"